# How to SELECT data from one table that meets all requirements in another table

Tags: oracle

I have a really simple table here with applicants, skills and another table with just skills. My goal is to see which applicants meet ALL requirements in the required skill table.

p1  Java
p1  Oracle
p2  Java
p2  C#
p2  Oracle
p3  C#

AND

Java
C#

```
SELECT a.NAME
FROM APPLICANTS a, SKILLS s
WHERE a.SKILL = s.SKILL
```

This returns me everyone except who ever has Oracle. Iv'e tried GROUP BY HAVING as well as what ever the book/internet have conjured in the past few hours. All I'm looking to have reported in this instance is p2. This is my first day with a database hands on but the idea of this task seems so simple yet I can't grasp it. Any help, hints, or clues would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some example of the rows in applicants and skills table

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the skills by people but limit the result to the people/skills combinations that have skills in the skills table

```
SELECT
    A.NAME, 
FROM
    APPLICANTS A
    INNER JOIN SKILLS ON S.SKILL = A.SKILL
GROUP BY
    A.NAME 
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SKILLS)
```

A person who has all skills will have a count of skills = the number of skills in the skills table.

This assumes that there is only one Person/skill combo in the table if you have multiple rows you should be able to use a sub query to get the Distinct rows first.

```
SELECT
    A.Name
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT NAME, SKILL FROM APPLICANTS) A
    INNER JOIN SKILLS ON S.SKILL = A.SKILL
GROUP BY
    A.SKILL 
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SKILLS)
```

Comment: Suppose, a person has skills Java and Oracle, Skills table has entries C++ and Perl, in that case also it will return Name, we cannot guarantee correct results just by matching counts, I guess.

Comment: Ahh i see what you're saying - yes there needs to be a join too. I've corrected it to limit the first table to only have those skills that are in the Skills table. Then the count is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be using scalar sub-query, to find language in skills tables for each skills of an applicant and then counting not nulls from the result

```
WITH APPLICANTS(P_ID, LANG) AS (
  SELECT 'p1', 'Java' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  select 'p1', 'Oracle' from dual union all
  SELECT 'P2', 'Java' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'P2', 'C#' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'p3', 'Oracle' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'p3', 'C#' FROM DUAL),
SKILLS (LANG) AS (
  SELECT 'Java' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C#'   FROM DUAL),
--------------
--End if data preparation
--------------
APPLICANTS_GROUP AS (SELECT P.P_ID, (SELECT S.LANG FROM SKILLS S WHERE S.LANG = P.LANG AND ROWNUM = 1) LANG
                       FROM APPLICANTS P)
SELECT p_id
  FROM APPLICANTS_GROUP
 WHERE LANG IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY P_ID
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT LANG) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LANG) FROM SKILLS);
```

Output:

```
| P_ID |
|------|
|   P2 |
```

So, query for your tables(APPLICANTS and SKILLS ) would be

```
WITH APPLICANTS_GROUP AS (SELECT P.P_ID, (SELECT S.LANG FROM SKILLS S WHERE S.LANG = P.LANG AND ROWNUM = 1) LANG
                            FROM APPLICANTS P)
SELECT p_id
  FROM APPLICANTS_GROUP
 WHERE LANG IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY P_ID
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT LANG) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LANG) FROM SKILLS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Preet Sangha, you put me on the correct track. I had no idea you could sub query a FROM statement. Looks like you went back and edited to exactly what I was going to point out. Previously those statements without the join on skill returned p1. Seemingly because p1 had 2 skills and there were only 2 required skills but it was not checking whether or not they were the correct skills. This is what I came to before your edit.

```
SELECT
    A.Name
FROM
   (SELECT APPLICANTS.Name, APPLICANTS.SKILL 
    FROM APPLICANTS, SKILLS
    WHERE APPLICANTS.SKILL = SKILLS.SKILL) A
GROUP BY
    A.Name
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SKILLS)
```